# Copying lists into columns of a table

Tags: vba, excel, time-limit-exceeded

Edit: I found a potential solution. Changing all of the `Dim as Long` to `Dim as Integer` allows the scripts to run smoother. However, there is a potential that the number of rows in some instances will exceed 32767. Is there a way I can put a condition on the first few statements, to use `integer` only if there are less than 30k rows?

The following script works to take a large dataset from this form in the Worksheet "List"

```
1    David
Eve
Freya
Sam
Yarra
2    Brian
David
Eva
Harry
Paul
3    Charlie
David
4    Eva
Harry
Paul
```

And paste it into another worksheet, "Library," like this:

```
1          2          3           4
David      Brian      Charlie     Eva
Eve        David      David       Harry
Freya      Eva                    Paul
Sam        Harry
Yarra      Paul
```

While generating a singleton list of one of each name in the worksheet "List".

The (long) code is pasted below. As I said before, it works fine with shorter lists, but not with larger ones (over 20,000), as it gives me a "Not responding" message where I'm forced to End Task. Is there anything else I can do to fix this? It has been suggested that I add DoEvents, but I'm not sure how I could implement this into the current script. Also, it taking long wouldn't bother me too much if I could have some sort of Progress Bar that updates at each step. Would that work as a DoEvent? All suggestions are welcome.

```
Sub RunAH_KeyWordLibrary()
Call PrepareKeywords
Call PrepareLibrary
End Sub

Private Sub PrepareKeywords()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
Dim Library As Worksheet
Dim List As Worksheet
Set Library = Sheets("Library")
Set List = Sheets("List")  

Dim Rng As Range
Dim i As Long 
Dim lastRow As Long 
i = 1 
lastRow = Library.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row

 While i <= lastRow 

 Set Rng = Library.Range("A" & i) 

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rng.Offset(0, 1)) = 1 Then 

Rng.Offset(0, 1).Cut 
Rng.Offset(1, 0).Insert Shift:=xlDown 
Rng.Offset(0, 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown 

ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rng.Offset(0, 1)) = 0 Then
i = i + 1


End If 
Wend 

      Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
      Application.EnableEvents = True
      Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
      Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Private Sub PrepareLibrary()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Library As Worksheet
Set Library = Sheets("Library")
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim results As Variant
    Dim resultsIndex As Long
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim currentColumn As Integer
    currentColumn = 1
    lastRow = Library.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    ReDim results(1 To lastRow)
    results = Library.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Value

    For resultsIndex = 1 To lastRow
        If IsNumeric(results(resultsIndex, 1)) Then
            currentColumn = currentColumn + 1
            Library.Cells(1, currentColumn) = results(resultsIndex, 1)
            currentRow = 2
        Else:
        Library.Cells(currentRow, currentColumn) = results(resultsIndex, 1)
        currentRow = currentRow + 1

        End If
     Next

     Sheets("Library").Select
        Cells.Replace What:="~*", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("List").Select
    Range("A1").PasteSpecial 

        Cells.Replace What:="~*", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False 
      Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

Call Order
Call RemoveNumber
Call MakeUpper
Call RemoveDuplicates
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.ClearContents 
End Sub


Private Sub Order() 
 Columns("A:A").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("list").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("list").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "A1:A30000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("list").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:A30000")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply 
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub RemoveNumber() 
Dim Rng As Range
Dim i As Long
i = 1
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim lastRow As Long
i = 1
lastRow = List.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row

While i <= lastRow
Set Rng = Range("A" & i)
If IsNumeric(Rng.Value) = True And Len(Rng.Value) > 0 Then
Rng.Delete Shift:=xlUp 
ElseIf IsNumeric(Rng.Value) = False Then
i = i + 1
Else: i = i + 1
End If
Wend
End Sub
Private Sub MakeUpper()
Dim C As Long
Dim List As Worksheet
Set List = Sheets("List")
C = List.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "=UPPER(RC[-1])" 
Range("B1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B1:B" & C), Type:=xlFillDefault 
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

End Sub
Private Sub RemoveDuplicates()

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range
Dim i As Long
i = 2
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = List.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row

While i <= lastRow
Set Rng = List.Range("A" & i)

If Rng = Rng.Offset(1, 0) And IsEmpty(Rng.Value) = False Then
Rng.Delete Shift:=xlUp
ElseIf Rng <> Rng.Offset(1, 0) And IsEmpty(Rng.Value) = False Then
i = i + 1

Else: i = i + 1
End If
Wend
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
      Application.EnableEvents = True
      Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
      Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Regarding your `Integer` vs `Long` concern: you have much bigger performance issues than the size of an integer. Use `Long` for row numbers, *regardless* of how many rows you're dealing with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your indentation is pretty much random, which makes code quite hard to read and to follow. Use the latest [Rubberduck](http://www.rubberduckvba.com) or [MZ-Tools](http://www.mztools.com/) VBE add-ins to automatically, properly and consistently indent your code.

Here's your code, after simply clicking *Indent Module* in Rubberduck (notice `Option Explicit`):

```
Option Explicit

Sub RunAH_KeyWordLibrary()
    Call PrepareKeywords
    Call PrepareLibrary
End Sub

Private Sub PrepareKeywords()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
    Dim Library As Worksheet
    Dim List As Worksheet
    Set Library = Sheets("Library")
    Set List = Sheets("List")

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    i = 1
    lastRow = Library.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    While i <= lastRow

        Set Rng = Library.Range("A" & i)

        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rng.Offset(0, 1)) = 1 Then

            Rng.Offset(0, 1).Cut
            Rng.Offset(1, 0).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            Rng.Offset(0, 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown

        ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rng.Offset(0, 1)) = 0 Then
            i = i + 1


        End If
    Wend

    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Private Sub PrepareLibrary()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim Library As Worksheet
    Set Library = Sheets("Library")
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim results As Variant
    Dim resultsIndex As Long
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim currentColumn As Integer
    currentColumn = 1
    lastRow = Library.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim results(1 To lastRow)
    results = Library.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Value

    For resultsIndex = 1 To lastRow
        If IsNumeric(results(resultsIndex, 1)) Then
            currentColumn = currentColumn + 1
            Library.Cells(1, currentColumn) = results(resultsIndex, 1)
            currentRow = 2
        Else:
            Library.Cells(currentRow, currentColumn) = results(resultsIndex, 1)
            currentRow = currentRow + 1

        End If
    Next

    Sheets("Library").Select
    Cells.Replace What:="~*", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("List").Select
    Range("A1").PasteSpecial

    Cells.Replace What:="~*", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

    Call Order
    Call RemoveNumber
    Call MakeUpper
    Call RemoveDuplicates
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
End Sub

Private Sub Order()
    Columns("A:A").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("list").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("list").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "A1:A30000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("list").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:A30000")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub RemoveNumber()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    i = 1
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim lastRow As Long
    i = 1
    lastRow = List.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    While i <= lastRow
        Set Rng = Range("A" & i)
        If IsNumeric(Rng.Value) = True And Len(Rng.Value) > 0 Then
            Rng.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        ElseIf IsNumeric(Rng.Value) = False Then
            i = i + 1
        Else: i = i + 1
        End If
    Wend
End Sub

Private Sub MakeUpper()
    Dim C As Long
    Dim List As Worksheet
    Set List = Sheets("List")
    C = List.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "=UPPER(RC[-1])"
    Range("B1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B1:B" & C), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

End Sub

Private Sub RemoveDuplicates()

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    i = 2
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = List.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    While i <= lastRow
        Set Rng = List.Range("A" & i)

        If Rng = Rng.Offset(1, 0) And IsEmpty(Rng.Value) = False Then
            Rng.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        ElseIf Rng <> Rng.Offset(1, 0) And IsEmpty(Rng.Value) = False Then
            i = i + 1

        Else: i = i + 1
        End If
    Wend
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Your usage of the *instruction separator* in `Else` blocks also contributes to make the code hard to read IMO (on top of confusing Rubberduck's indenter, [#1508](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/issues/1508)), but anyway the point is that properly indented code is much easier to read... and to debug.

Your Boolean logic could be simplified in this block here:

> ```
> If Rng = Rng.Offset(1, 0) And IsEmpty(Rng.Value) = False Then
> Rng.Delete Shift:=xlUp
> ElseIf Rng <> Rng.Offset(1, 0) And IsEmpty(Rng.Value) = False Then
> i = i + 1
>
> Else: i = i + 1
> End If
> ```

To this:

```
If Rng = Rng.Offset(1, 0) And Not IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then
    Rng.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Else
    i = i + 1
End If
```

Avoid turning Boolean values into Boolean expressions (`IsEmpty` function returns a `Boolean` value, *therefore* it *is* a Boolean expression) - comparing a Boolean to `True` or `False` is perfectly redundant.

Also, whenever two or more branches of an `If..Else` block result in the same code being executed, *something* isn't right with the logic.

Your usage of line continuations is questionnable, too:

> ```
> Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
>     :=False, Transpose:=False
> ```

The `SkipBlanks` parameter's name is on one line, and its value is on another; this defeats the purpose of line continuations, which exist to help *improve* the readability of long lines.

```
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                       Operation:=xlNone, _
                       SkipBlanks:=False, _
                       Transpose:=False
```

You don't have to put each argument on its own line, but you should avoid splitting an instruction in the middle of a parameter.

---

You're not consistent about explicit vs implicit sheet references either. Sometimes you'll do `Library.Range("A1")` and other times you'll refer to `Range`, `Cells` and `Columns` without qualifying these function calls with an worksheet object, which makes them implicitly reference *whatever worksheet is currently active* - and solid, reliable Excel VBA code doesn't rely on `Select` and `Activate` (macro recorder code does, and macro recorder code is incredibly frail).

Prime example here:

```
Private Sub Order()
    Columns("A:A").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("list").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("list").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "A1:A30000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("list").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:A30000")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Could be written as:

```
Private Sub SortListSheet()
    Dim target As Worksheet
    Set target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("List")
    With target.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=target.Range("A1:A30000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange target.Range("A1:A30000")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Notice that the two `Range` calls are now fully qualified, which prevents a runtime error if the user happens to select another worksheet between the moment execution starts in that procedure, and the moment the `.SortFields.Add` (or `.SetRange`) method is called.

Also notice there's no `.Select` or `Selection` that needs to get involved at any point. That said, I'm not sure `"A1:A30000"` is the ideal way of doing what you're trying to do here. What happens the day there's 30,001 rows in column A? Clearly you need a better way to [find out what the last row is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11169920/1188513).

---

The `Call` keyword doesn't serve any purpose really. This:

```
Sub RunAH_KeyWordLibrary()
    Call PrepareKeywords
    Call PrepareLibrary
End Sub
```

Is exactly the same as this:

```
Sub RunAH_KeyWordLibrary()
    PrepareKeywords
    PrepareLibrary
End Sub
```

If you *consistently* name your procedures the way you should, by making their names start with a verb, it shouldn't be "hard" to tell what's a procedure in your code.

---

You repeat this code in several places:

```
Application.Calculation = some value
Application.EnableEvents = some value
Application.DisplayStatusBar = some value
Application.EnableEvents = some value
```

Dont' Repeat Yourself. Write it once in a procedure dedicated to this, give it a parameter that determines whether to toggle it on or off, and then call the procedure when you need it, instead of copy-pasting code all over the place.

---

This code relies on active selection:

```
Sheets("Library").Select
Cells.Replace What:="~*", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Columns("A:A").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("List").Select
Range("A1").PasteSpecial
```

You already have an object reference for that "Library" sheet - *use it*! Make another for the destination worksheet, and you can do what the above code does in 3 little statements:

```
Library.Cells.Replace ...
Library.Columns("A:A").Copy
List.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
```

---

`DoEvents` would help improve *responsiveness*, but is actually going to make the performance *worse*. Excel going "not responding" doesn't mean the code stopped running; it means Excel isn't repainting itself while it's busy running your macro.

Consider extracting a procedure that turns screen updating on, updates the status bar with some progress message, and then turns screen updating back off; set `Application.StatusBar = vbNullString` when you're done, to give Excel back its status bar.

First step in improving performance, is to remove `Select` and `Activate`, and change all the code that relies on an `ActiveSheet`, be it implicitly or explicitly. Then you need to minimize the actual worksheet-handling code - the single slowest thing you can do in VBA is manipulate (be it reading or writing) a spreadsheet, so you need to write code that does that as little as possible, and only when needed - for example it's better to copy a whole range in memory as an array, and iterate that array, than iterate the cells in that range on that worksheet. Avoid `WorksheetFunctions` in VBA code (very often there's an equivalent "native" VBA function for it anyway).

Comment: If you put all your `Application.` calls into a separate function, make sure your error handler puts them back!

Comment: Thanks a million, Mat. I'll learned a lot from this post. Cheers!

Comment: @user1996971 sorry I forgot to put a disclaimer... I manage the GitHub repository for the Rubberduck project.

Answer (score 4):

[Mat has covered most everything](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/128503/75587). But,

In `RemoveDuplicates` and I'll assume `List` is a codename (or not declared) for a sheet, why not do the same for `Library`?

Worksheets have a `CodeName` property - View Properties window (<kbd>F4</kbd>) and the `(Name)` field (the one at the top) can be used as the worksheet name. This way you can avoid `Sheets("mySheet")` and instead just use `mySheet`.

---

```
If IsNumeric(Rng.Value) = True And Len(Rng.Value) > 0 Then
```

Doing something like `If method = True then` is redundant, you can just say `If method then`

Things like

```
And IsEmpty(Rng.Value) = False
```

are better understood by structuring them like this

```
And Not IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then
```

---

I do want to say **good job** on (declaring and) giving variables *meaningful names* and following [Standard VBA naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s46s4ew(v=vs.140).aspx).